# Redux Form always validates even on a normal button press

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux form with a submit button and a normal html button. I dont want the form to be validated when the normal button is pressed. But looks like the form is always validated once and then when I click the button again the onclick on the button is executed. How do I prevent this?

I replicated the same issue with same form. For example if you go to http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/syncValidation/ ,enter 4 in the age field and click on clear values. First time the validation triggers and stops the button action. Second time the button action works i.e, the form values are cleared..

Comment: I don't think the buttons are the issue. As far as I can see they're just regular html buttons. One is of type `submit` the other `button`. Only the first should trigger the `onSubmit` handler on the form. What I think you're seeing is that the form fields validation on blur, i.e. when they lose focus. That'll happen if you enter an invalid value and immediately click anywhere else on the screen (like a `clear` button). That'll momentarily validate the input before acting on the button event.

Comment: Thanks for this. But as you can see in the sample in the first instance the "clear" action is not executed. I have to press the clear button twice to have the form cleared. How can I prevent / work around this?

Comment: I tried repeatedly and most of the time I only had to click once to clear it. It did occasionally need to be clicked twice, I'll see if I can find out under which circumstances.

Comment: Add `type="button"` to prevent the button from submitting the form.

Comment: @OB3 The clear button is already `type="button"`.

Perhaps the issue is that the input blur validation sometimes finishes after the clear handler has finished, thus resetting the form state to before the reset action was dispatched.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen Sorry, didn't see that your comment. A wild guess: the validation message that appears "pushes" the button down, so "click" is not triggered. The second time it's already there, so when they release the mouse button, the button is still in the same position and "click" is triggered.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The example you link to has that behavior because by default Redux Form will call the validation function for touched Fields on a blur event. The fact that you are clicking a button is irrelevant - you could click on any element or anywhere on the page and you would get that behavior.

The only real way to stop this behavior is to stop Redux Form from touching your Fields on a blur event. You can do this by setting `touchOnBlur` to `false` in the Redux Form config object.

```
export default reduxForm({ form: 'myForm', touchOnBlur: false })(MyForm);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However this means I will lose validation on blur.  I agree that the validation will happen, but why does action get stopped. I have to press the button twice in order to perform the event required. My button is not part of the form, its outside the form, and when I click it, irrespetive on any error on the form it should call the function onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add type="button" to prevent the button from submitting the form.If you don't give any type it will consider submit.